# Update specific field on all custom object records except for last edited

Tags: workflow

I have custom object that have "Default Something" checkbox field. What I want to achieve is to have maximum one record that have "Default Something" checked. I tried the workflow rule but I didn't manage to achieve what I want. Creating a whole custom visualforce page and extension just to override the "Save" button seems like very complicated solution. For clarification, the logic is supposed to be:
if(DefaultSomething)
    Update all records to DefaultSomething=NO WHERE Id!=LastUpdated(Created)Record

Comment: Did you try do it in a trigger?

Comment: Thank you! It did the job. Post it as a answer and I will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a trigger that will do it but you need to make sure to avoid recursion. The trigger could be one way to do it. See [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000133752&language=en_US) for more details on how to stop the trigger recursion.

```
trigger updateTrigger on anyObject(after update) {

    if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) {
        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        for (anyObject ao : Trigger.new) {     
            if (ao.DefaultSomething__c) {
                ids.add(ao.SomeId__c);
             }  
        }

        List<anyObject> toUpdate = [select Id from anyObject 
                                          where DefaultSomething__c = true 
                                          and SomeId__c in :ids];
        for (anyObject ao : toUpdate) {
            toUpdate.DefaultSomething__c = false;
        }
        if (toUpdate.size() > 0) {
            update toUpdate;
        }    
    }
}
```